# Задача - найти количество счастливых билетов длинны N

Tags: c++

Решаю данную задачу путём ДП, с помощью табличных значений (метод есть на
[Хабре](https://habr.com/post/266479/)).
Для билетов из 2,4,6,8,10 чисел считаен всё правильно. А дальше - ошибки, например для 12 - 926464756, ответ должен быть 39581170420. 

 В чём может быть ошибка?

Код с++

```
int N;
cin >> N;

int ArrSize = (N / 2) * 9+1;
int *Arr = new int[ArrSize];
int *ArrCounter = new int[ArrSize];

for (int i = 0; i < ArrSize; i++)
{
    Arr[i] = 0;
    ArrCounter[i] = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ArrCounter[i] = 1;
}
Arr[0] = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <=N/2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <=i*9; j++)
    {
        if (j < 10)
        {
            for (int posJ = j; posJ >= 0; posJ--)
            {
                Arr[j] += ArrCounter[posJ];
            }

        }
        else
        {
            for (int posJ = j; posJ > j - 10; posJ--)
            {
                Arr[j] += ArrCounter[posJ];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < ArrSize; j++)
    {
        ArrCounter[j] = Arr[j];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < ArrSize; i++)
    {

        Arr[i] = 0;
    }
}

int CountLuckyTickets = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < ArrSize ; j++)
{
    CountLuckyTickets+=ArrCounter[j]*ArrCounter[j];
}
cout << CountLuckyTickets<<endl;
```

[image: Таблица]

Comment: Полагаю, число не влезает в int: 39581170420 % (2**32) == 926464756

Comment: @Anton, спасибо, вполне может из-за этого ошибка, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Anton Действительно, глупая ошибка, спасибо, всё заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была за малым, в int не влезал результат.

Соответственно int заменить на long long